# Rename git folder

Tags: git, directory, rename, gitlab

I got my project on gitlab with path: 
project\classes\Controller\API\filename.php

I need to rename my API folder to Api
project\classes\Controller\Api\filename.php

Is there some way (git command) to do that instead of removing folder and push it again?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use [git mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)

e.g.

```
git mv project\classes\Controller\API project\classes\Controller\Api
```

I don't have windows, so I'm not sure about this one, but you may need to make git case sensitive with this command:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `git mv`.

Due to the way that git store the content, it does not care what is the file name just its content as you can see in the image below.

The most right column is the content while the middle one is the "names" of the files & folders.

If you will simply rename the files in your workdir, git will not update its internal storage. In order to "tell" git to rename the file you must use the `git mv` command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are just changing case sensitive like: **utils to Utils**
Then first rename as **utils** as **temp**, and from **temp** to **Utils**

**Note:-** Don't forgot to mention path from root like- packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/

```
git mv packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/Configure packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/temp
git mv packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/temp packages/client/src/modules/query-browser/pages/configure
```